# How do I refresh CSS after javascript runs to adjust div height

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following script to adjust the height of a container div on my page relative to the browser window's height

```
function thirty_pc() {
var height = $(window).height();
var thirtypc = (50 * height) / 100;
thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
var thirtypc2 = thirtypc * 2;
$("#slider").css('height',thirtypc);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
thirty_pc();
$(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
});
```

The script works fine to scale the #slider div's height relative to the viewport's height.  The problem is if I resize the browser window the inside div elements dimensions get distorted.  However if I refresh the browser the inside div elements fix themselves.  Also if I go into firebug while the inside div's are distorted and I un-check ANY even unrelated elements CSS properties, the inside div's fix themselves.

Would the solution be for javascript to somehow refresh CSS after a browser re-size?  If so how do you do that?  Or should I be tying in the effected inside div element's dimensions to the function to begin with?  I have also tried to do that with no luck.

The fact that a browser or CSS refresh seems to fix the problem makes me lean towards the first solution if it's possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a link or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?  We really need to see the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I suggest you *make* a text space... a simplified version to learn with. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5K4C9/) as an example how you can make an example that doesn't have all the other site stuff in the way. CSS is read once. the js is writing inline CSS. So you don't want to refresh the CSS. You want to write new inline CSS over the stuff the js already wrote.

Here is an example of a function. Below is how you call it on DOM ready and then, also when the window is resized. Keep in mind that it is going to run that function many many many times while you resize - so this isn't great for all scenarios. Also, - while it's commendable that you want it to resize(I do the same) no one else is going to resize their browser... So pick your battles.

```
var your_functions_name = function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.box').css('height', windowHeight/2);
};

// run on document ready
$(document).ready(your_functions_name);

// run on window resize
$(window).resize(your_functions_name);
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try to make a jsfiddle for this.  Even though I understand that the javascript is writing inline css, I still don't understand why un-clicking a random css value in firebug on any element on the page immediately fixes my problem.  Can't I force the browser to do whatever it is that happens when you make a random change in firebug.  It must be refreshing "something" on the page somewhere.

Comment: Also I don't fully understand what to do with the 2 different instances you mentioned.  I though that right now the function is being called under document ready because it works when the browser is loaded and continues to work when it's re-sized.  However the problem only happens when it's resized

Comment: Actually I just figured it out...
I had to add the line "$(".slideimg").css('height',thirtypc);" to the end of the function.  .slideimg is the div inside the container div.  When the height of the container div is adjusted by the js function, the inner divs still think the height of the outer div is what it was when the page loaded, they don't adjust on the fly, only when the browser is loaded.  So by adding that line the inner divs height adjustment is included in the function