# specific image resize with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I've been trying for sometime to replicate an effect seen on this website:

http://www.gregparmasmith.com/

If you play around with the width and height of the window, the images keep proportionate w/h based on their aspect ratio. The images are always loaded with a consistent height, making this slideshow look very nice.

Also notice how wider images (vs thinner images) are resized when just the width of the browser window (not width and height together) is reduced - The images bounce down from the top margin.

He seems to be programming this differently than most responsive jquery image plugins I've seen. There is a parent div container, but it has a static size and seems to not govern the position/sizing of its child images.

Looking at the source, the images top,left,width,height css properties are dynamically being altered.

Any suggestions for how to do this??

Comment: You should try to do that using CSS. I'm certain that it is possible. Try and search a bit. All that javascript is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The effect seen on that page can be accomplished with just html and css.  No javascript needed.  He's using percentages as the values for his margins so that as the browser size gets smaller, so does the calculated pixel size of the left and right margins of the div that contains the images.  Then by setting the img width to a max-width of a fixed pixel size, say 400px, it will ensure it will only reach a certain width as it does on very large screens.
Then by setting the "width" to a percentage like maybe 100% the image will automatically resize to the size of the containing div because that div is responding the size of the browser.
something like this:

```
#inside  {
max-width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 20%;
margin-bottom: 20%;
}
#inside img  {
width: 100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wRNJ7/1/

Comment: ok, this does look good.. But check out [http://www.gregparmasmith.com/12](http://www.gregparmasmith.com/12). Shrink the browser just by its width, NOT by height. See how the image gets pushed off the top and bottom margins while simultaneously being resized. That seems to using something more than just css.

Comment: yea you're right.  it must be using the jquery function $( window ).height(); to determine viewport height and change the css height value accordingly

Comment: I solved a similar problem in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122854/how-do-i-refresh-css-after-javascript-runs-to-adjust-div-height

Comment: I have found a pretty close solution here:

Answer (score 0):

I have found a pretty close solution here in this thread:

[Vertically center image on page and maintain aspect ratio on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355111/vertically-center-image-on-page-and-maintain-aspect-ratio-on-resize)

Here's a good working demo:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FAzBq/1/show/)

```
html, body {height: 100%}

body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;      
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
img {
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

This effect is achieved without any javascript, which at first I thought was undoable. In this demo, the action of the resizing is a little different. In the original website I was trying to model (http://www.gregparmasmith.com/12), it is **"clear"** that resizing happens only when necessary, so that for a thin image (ex. 500x100): When the browser window is made as thin, no shrinking would occur. Resizing of the image would occur only if the width of the image would exceed the width of the browser.

In this jsfiddle, I think I can notice this same action is happening, but it's not as obvious.